# LinkedIn Share API stopped working for my domain about a week ago

Tags: share, linkedin-api, internal-server-error

I started to receive problems with sharing from LinkedIN last week. Prior to last week shares were working fine. When I try to share an article, their share program appears to go into a loop. The linkedIN share page comes up but it just spins and spins and spins.

This is the url – encoded url and encoded title.

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fcs%2F24912%2F39%2Fnull%2F93538%2F&title=Is+There+Still+a+Place+for+Print+Marketing%3F

When I look in the developer tools on chrome it appears that the page is in some kind of loop.  As it keeps loading the following share page over and over…

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain%2Ecom%2Fcs%2F24912%2F39%2Fnull%2F93538%2F&title=Is+There+Still+a+Place+for+Print+Marketing%3F&trk=LI_BADGE_OLD

So I do the exact same call, just change the url to google

And it works.

I also have an app that is behaving the same way – when I post using the app – with rw permissions, I get an internal service error if I use my domain but I can post successfully using google.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved. The domain was listed in SPAMHAUS DBL (incorrectly, but that's a subject for another day). De-listed it and things are back to normal. LINKEDIN It would be great to return the real error versus an internal server error. For anyone that runs into this problem, check SMAPHAUS DBL listing.