# What does 416 Failure returned by Post Inspector mean?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have two questions,

1. My organization has 6 different websites, and all use ShareArticle to create a link to share information. But, ShareArticle does not work for one site(APA.org: https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.apas.org%2f), the other 5 work fine.
2. I used Post Inspector to inspect http://www.apa.org and received "416 Failure", what does this mean?

I'd appreciate any suggestions.  Thank you very much for your kind attention.

Tang

A web developer from LinkedIn suggested we use Microsoft plugin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin), I tested and received the "Oops!" error as before.

I went through all the ShareArticle related posts on Stack Overflow with no luck, 
 --- WWW.apa.org in not on SPAMHAUS DBL (Solved the issue in this post because they are on SPAMHAUS DBL,  [LinkedIn Share API stopped working for my domain about a week ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393204/linkedin-share-api-stopped-working-for-my-domain-about-a-week-ago))
 --- found a post ([Linkedin post inspector can't display preview for my webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986653/linkedin-post-inspector-cant-display-preview-for-my-webpage)) gave me the idea to check on  different configurations/settings on different sites, nothing found.

The following are two sample urls, the first one is the one we are having trouble with, the second one works fine.

APA.org: https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.apas.org%2f

APAStyle.org: https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.apastyle.org%2f

I'd appreciate any suggestions/thoughts on why the first one is not working.

APA.org: https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.apas.org%2f

And, what "416 Failure" mean? Thank you very much for your kind attention.

Comment: Is this HTTP status 416?  [Range not satisfiable](https://httpstatuses.com/416)

Comment: Thank you very much, Dave.  When I use LinkedIn Post Inspector to exam the failed url and received a "416 Failure" in the "URL redirect trail", do you by any chance how do I fix the issue?  Thanks, again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Post Inspector. If the 416 status is caused by a bad Content-Range header in the request, what controls the range requested?   Input from you, or is it magically provided by Post Inspector?  That's the key question.

Comment: Does this issue still happen for you?  I don't get the 416 above with either of your links but then again this question is several years old.